# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to resolve this error:

Code:

```
X = np.array(pd.read_csv('my_X_table1-1c.csv',header=None).values)
y = np.array(pd.read_csv('my_y_table1-1c.csv',header=None).values.ravel())
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)

def Ridgecv(alpha):
    return cross_val_score(Ridge(alpha=float(alpha), random_state=2),
                           X_train, y_train, 'mae', cv=5).mean()
```

The error is related to `X_train, y_train`:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1052, 1052, 3]
```

Comment: what's the result for X_train.shape and y_train.shape?

Comment: @oW_ Thanks. They respectively are (1052, 60) and (1052, ).

Comment: Try y_train.reshape((1052,1))

Comment: @oW_ Thanks. I tried y_train.reshape(len(y_train),1) but unfortunately the same error is reported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that I missed the word "scoring". In fact, the extra 3 was related to the number of characters of 'mae'.

```
def Ridgecv(alpha):
    return cross_val_score(Ridge(alpha=float(alpha), random_state=2),
                           X_train, y_train, scoring='mae', cv=5).mean()
```

Comment: Wow had the same bug ... hard one to spot! Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score -1):

It should be in sequence:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,random_state=101,test_size=0.3)
```

and then it should be in fit method(x_train,y train)

Comment: sorry, the error is related to how to define parameters of `cross_val_score`.